# why is the pipe so slow in this case?

Tags: r, performance, dplyr, ode

I've got a model in R that is running very slowly and I've figured out that it is purely due to a very small number of lines of code which use the pipe that are within an ode solver. Does anyone know why this is slowing it down so much? Is there a faster way to do it?

Example code:

```
IDS <- c(1,1,2)
output <- runif(3, 0, 100)
ID_df1 <- data.frame(IDS, output)
ID_df <- ID_df1 %>% 
  group_by(IDS) %>% 
  summarise(totals = sum(output))
portions <- ID_df1 %>% 
  left_join(ID_df, by = "IDS") %>% 
  mutate(portion = output/totals) %>% 
  select(IDS, portion)
```

Comment: If you just want to (slightly) speed up, use this: `ID_df1 %>% group_by(IDS) %>% mutate(portion = output / sum(output))`, since the join is not necessary. Otherwise, make a proper example showing your actual problem.

Comment: or maybe using `data.table` like `library(data.table); setDT(ID_df1)[, .(output = output / sum(output)), by=.(IDS)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

base R's `tapply` will run faster.

```
ID_df1$portion <- unlist(tapply(ID_df1$output, ID_df1$IDS, function(x) x / sum(x)))
```

For comparison (I'm using a data frame of 10,000 rows and 100 distinct `IDS`)

```
set.seed(pi)
IDS <- sample(1:100, size = 10000, replace = TRUE)
output <- runif(3, 0, 10000)
ID_df1 <- data.frame(IDS, output)

library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  orig = {
    ID_df <- ID_df1 %>% 
      group_by(IDS) %>% 
      summarise(totals = sum(output))
    portions <- ID_df1 %>% 
      left_join(ID_df, by = "IDS") %>% 
      mutate(portion = output/totals) %>% 
      select(IDS, portion)
  },
  tino = {
    ID_df1 %>% group_by(IDS) %>% mutate(portion = output / sum(output))
  },
  data.table = {
    setDT(ID_df1)[, .(portion = output / sum(output)), by=.(IDS)]
  },
  base = {
    ID_df1$portion <- unlist(tapply(ID_df1$output, ID_df1$IDS, function(x) x / sum(x)))
  }
)

# Unit: microseconds
#        expr       min        lq       mean     median         uq       max neval cld
#        orig 11936.111 12101.798 12705.9227 12310.2980 12914.0975 22949.662   100   c
#        tino  5224.230  5370.854  5636.8930  5558.3875  5734.9235  8466.684   100  b 
#  data.table   569.490   594.856   768.6615   724.4725   777.2565  3279.110   100 a  
#        base   497.937   524.623   606.8760   602.9200   650.2800  1933.098   100 a
```

Answer (score 1):

suggestion to use data.table. some timing comparison below:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(30L)
N <- 1e6
IDS <- sample(LETTERS, N, replace=TRUE)
output <- runif(N, 0, 100)
ID_df1 <- data.frame(IDS, output)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    #as suggested by @Tino
    mtd_dplyr=ID_df1 %>% group_by(IDS) %>% mutate(portion = output / sum(output)),
    mtd_data.table=setDT(ID_df1)[, .(portion = output / sum(output)), by=.(IDS)],
    mtd_base=do.call(rbind, by(ID_df1, ID_df1$IDS, function(x) data.frame(x$IDS, portion=x$output/sum(x$output)))),
    times=10L
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#            expr       min        lq       mean     median        uq       max neval
#       mtd_dplyr   96.9382   99.0871  117.64655  114.47100  133.0421  144.6009    10
#  mtd_data.table   15.7899   21.1913   30.93596   21.37835   25.5830   81.5951    10
#        mtd_base 1191.5829 1245.0176 1392.00927 1369.00735 1450.2118 1859.3708    10
```

Comment: is there a way to do this that doesn't reorder everything when you use tapply. At the moment what it does is reorder everything by ID, but if the data don't fit that pattern it gives the wrong result. So for example if B comes after A in the list of IDs then A will get B's portion and B will get A's

Comment: the output looks like this: 11  12   2  31  32  33  34 
0.5 0.5  1 0.1 0.7 0.1 0.1

Comment: @DomBurns i think you left your comments on the wrong post.